# Prometheus Server on EKS with Helm - FailedScheduling

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I’m trying to install a fresh Prometheus Chart into my AWS EKS cluster using the community helm-chart [repo](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts).

However, alertmanager and prometheus-server pods fail to start. They both show an event warning:

```
Warning FailedScheduling 10m (x25 over 4h13m) default-scheduler running PreBind plugin “VolumeBinding”: binding volumes: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Our EKS cluster is using EKS managed EC2 nodes, if that’s relevant. Anyone run into this before trying to set up Prometheus on AWS? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Steps:

Installed the helm chart via
`helm install <chartName> prometheus-community/prometheus -n <namespaceName>`

I verified the chart was deployed via
`kubectl get pods -n <namespaceName>`

Two pods do not start - prometheus-server and alert-manager. The logs from each pod say the same thing:
`Warning  FailedScheduling  5m22s (x1019 over 7d4h)  default-scheduler  running PreBind plugin "VolumeBinding": binding volumes: timed out waiting for the condition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, and default Prometheus chart values for `prometheus-server` ([here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml#L379)) & `alertmanager` ([here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml#L1138)), it's waiting for the PVC to be created. Is the [EBS CSI driver add-on](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html) installed on the cluster? As of EKS 1.23 ([changelog here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html#kubernetes-1.23)), the in-tree storage plugin has been replaced, which means a CSI driver like the one provided in EBS add-on will be needed in order to provision EBS volumes.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the problem and installing the driver add-on helped resolve our issue. 

For anyone else in this state, know that the driver will install 2 pods per node. If using EC2, there are limits to the number of IP addresses that can be assigned per namespace depending on the EC2 size. We had to redeploy our cluster on larger nodes to fully bring up our monitoring stack because we ran our of IP addresses.